# Is there any client side API available (e.g. -CSOM or Rest) to capture version for a Document Set in SharePoint Online?

Tags: rest, csom, sharepoint-online

Is there any client side API available (e.g. -CSOM or Rest) to capture version for a document in SharePoint Online ?

Comment: Hi @Samik, Though I didn't tried this but Pz look into this: http://yadavnitinkumar.blogspot.in/2014/12/adding-new-version-in-version.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the file versions out using CSOM by asking for the file and its versions. This example pulls the versions out for all files in a given list, but if you have the file reference, you would only need to load its `Versions` property.

```
var collection = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
clientContext.Load(collection, items => items.Include(
    i => i.File,
    i => i.File.Versions));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

var item = collection.Single();

foreach (var version in item.File.Versions)
{
    // Do work here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the need here is to store the version data.

Comment: Is there a way to obtain the File object for the version variable or the Level of approval property for that version file?